# Accessing Object using JAXB in Spring-JPA application

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jaxb

Please help me in accessing Employee object in the below code using JAXB annotations. The application was developed in JPA  SPRING. We are unable to access sub-object properties i.e, Employee properties

### RESOURCE CORE FILE

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name="resource")
@Entity
@Table(name = "resource")
public class Resource implements java.io.Serializable {


    private Integer resourceId;
    private String resourceCode;
    private String resourceName;
    private String resourceNumber;
    private Employee employee;


    public Resource() {
    }


    public Resource(Employee employee,String resourceCode, String resourceName,
            String resourceNumber
            ) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.resourceCode = resourceCode;
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.resourceNumber = resourceNumber;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "resource_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getResourceId() {
        return this.resourceId;
    }

    public void setResourceId(Integer resourceId) {
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }

    @Column(name = "resource_code")
    public String getResourceCode() {
        return this.resourceCode;
    }

    public void setResourceCode(String resourceCode) {
        this.resourceCode = resourceCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "resource_number")
    public String getResourceNumber() {
        return this.resourceNumber;
    }

    public void setResourceNumber(String resourceNumber) {
        this.resourceNumber = resourceNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "resource_name")
    public String getResourceName() {
        return this.resourceName;
    }

    public void setResourceName(String resourceName) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return this.employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

}
```

### EMPLOYEE CORE FILE

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name="employee")
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {


    private Integer employeeId;
    private String employeeCode;
    private String employeeName;
    private List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<Resource>(0);



    public Employee() {
    }



    public Employee(String employeeCode, String employeeName,List<Resource> resources

            ) {
        this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.resources = resources;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return this.employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    @Column(name = "employee_code")
    public String getEmployeeCode() {
        return this.employeeCode;
    }

    public void setEmployeeCode(String employeeCode) {
        this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
    }


    @Column(name = "employee_name")
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return this.employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employee")
    public List<Resource> getResources() {
        return this.resources;
    }

    public void setResources(List<Resource> resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Can you specify where the problem exactly occurs?

Comment: Your `employee` field isn't marked with either a JAXB annotation nor a JPA annotation. You need to add a `@XmlElement` annotation to the `employee` field in your `Resource` class.

Comment: Just noticed the accessor mode. Instead of putting it on the field put it on the getter/setter of employee.

Comment: Hi! Deinum thanks for the reply, which JaxB annotation should be used on the employee in resource class to access employee data

Comment: Hi Pieter, I didnt get any error but I'm unable to access Employee data through Resource. Im getting only Resource data if I had annotated Employee Object with @XmlTransient  but here I need Employee data with Resource Object data since Employee is a sub-object in Resource.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the FetchType : Eager in RESOURCE CORE FILE of getEmployee() Method. Lazy fetch type is pulling only the parent object. Eager is pulling both.